# how to Validate multiple email addresses in single textfield using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: textfield]

**Validation should match the following requirement.**

1. Email id should be separated by comma and semicolon;
2. Same email Id won't be repeated in the input field.

the regular expression or find some other way to do it.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: If your goal is to validate all email addresses at once, you have to separate them first with `split()` then loop through the returned array then validate each one.

Comment: please see this link: https://jsfiddle.net/Lswa073c/. on focus out, I am validating it  If it is empty string I am allowing it but if they enter other value

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service. What have you tried so far? Show us that you put some effort into your question. If you need a place to start, you could look into how to split strings at a given character / symbol. ´;´ in your case. Plenty of information on validating E-mails after that.

Comment: please see this link: https://jsfiddle.net/Lswa073c/. on focus out, I am validating it  If it is the empty string I am allowing it but if they enter other value I am validating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for reference, Split and validate emails.

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(email));
}
const validate = (emails = "") => {
  emails = emails.split(/[;,]/).map((x) => x.trim().toLocaleLowerCase());
  if (emails.length !== new Set(emails).size) return false;
  return emails.every(validateEmail);
};
console.log(validate("a@d.com"));
console.log(validate("a@d.com;b@sn.com"));
console.log(validate("ad.com"));
console.log(validate("a@sd.com,d@.c"));
console.log(validate("a@sd.com,d@gs.co"));
console.log(validate("a@sd.com;a@sd.com"));
```

Comment: If they enter same email id console.log(validate("a@sd.com,a@sd.com")); also i need false or repeated email id also

Comment: updated plz check.